# Asp.net User Control with underlying control editor functionality

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, user-controls

ASP.Net 3.5

I want to create a user control that contains the ListView and DataPager controls along with some custom code in the ItemDataBound that is generic and deals with UI styling.

Ideally, when the developer uses this control, I would like to retain editor support so they can select a datasource, add/remove columns,  etc...

Is this easy? If so, any references on how to do this?

If it is not possible, what alternatives are there?

The reason I am trying to create the user control is to make it easier on the developers to retain the ui look and feel and to encapsulate common UI styling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to delegate the exposed designer properties to the composed inner controls.

In my opinion it's honestly not worth the effort it would take to wire up nicely.

Comment: Do you think using an extender control may help?